# CakePHP production; Apache VirtualHost gradually stopped working

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, ubuntu

Disclaimer: New to Devops and originally from a Windows development background. Ignorance should be expected. Apologies in advance

So I'vejust started working on a server running Ubuntu on Apache (details below)

Server Version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1

My problem started two weeks ago (not exactly sure when), one of 3 virtual hosts we're using started getting slow (the other two are just fine). It eventually started giving the following errors in Chrome & FF respectively:

> Chrome: No data received. Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
>
> FF: The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

I've checked in so many places and made so many changes I've honestly lost track of what I've done. However all changes made to *.conf files have been followed by a $ service apache2 restart and I've even tried to uncover the source of the problem but my error.log files aren't displaying anything I can figure out on my own

Server-status output below:

> Current Time: Tuesday, 02-Sep-2014 11:16:08 UTC
>   Restart Time: Tuesday, 02-Sep-2014 09:15:37 UTC
>   Parent Server Generation: 0
>   Server uptime: 2 hours 31 seconds
>   Total accesses: 262 - Total Traffic: 8 kB
>   CPU Usage: u20.41 s6.89 cu.06 cs0 - .378% CPU load
>   .0362 requests/sec - 1 B/second - 31 B/request
>   1 requests currently being processed, 9 idle workers
>
> Srv    PID Acc M   CPU SS  Req Conn    Child   Slot    Client  VHost   Request
>
> 0-0    13881   0/33/33 _   3.97    365 100 0.0 0.00    0.00    IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1 ip-172-31-44-39.eu-west-1.compu GET /courses/amazoncron HTTP/1.1
>
> 1-0    21596   0/4/26  _   1.44    944 20390   0.0 0.00    0.00    IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1 dev.mydomain.com    GET /courses/amazoncron HTTP/1.1
>
> 2-0    -   0/0/32  .   2.81    2183    0   0.0 0.00    0.00    IP2.IP2.IP2.IP2 ip-172-31-44-39.eu-west-1.compu NULL
>
> 3-0    19851   0/11/23 _   2.54    360 5906    0.0 0.00    0.00    IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1 qa.mydomain.com GET /courses/amazoncron HTTP/1.1
>
> 4-0    13885   0/27/27 _   3.86    338 28472   0.0 0.00    0.00    IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1 dev.mydomain.com    GET /courses/amazoncron HTTP/1.1
>
> 5-0    -   0/0/27  .   2.73    2184    0   0.0 0.00    0.00    IP2.IP2.IP2.IP2 ip-172-31-44-39.eu-west-1.compu NULL
>
> 6-0    21597   0/3/17  _   1.78    956 8632    0.0 0.00    0.00    IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1 qa.mydomain.com GET /courses/amazoncron HTTP/1.1
>
> 7-0    21562   0/8/19  _   1.36    364 2069    0.0 0.00    0.00    IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1 mydomain.com    GET /courses/amazoncron HTTP/1.1
>
> 8-0    -   0/0/14  .   0.43    2118    16  0.0 0.00    0.00    IP2.IP2.IP2.IP2 ip-172-31-44-39.eu-west-1.compu NULL
>
> 9-0    21563   0/2/10  _   0.92    964 208 0.0 0.00    0.00    IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1 ip-172-31-44-39.eu-west-1.compu GET /courses/amazoncron HTTP/1.1
>
> 10-0   19351   0/17/17 _   3.18    954 9621    0.0 0.00    0.00    IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1 mydomain.com    GET /courses/amazoncron HTTP/1.1
>
> 11-0   21598   0/3/3   _   0.78    1542    23780   0.0 0.00    0.00    IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1 dev.mydomain.com    GET /courses/amazoncron HTTP/1.1
>
> 14-0   19859   0/12/12 W   1.46    0   0   0.0 0.00    0.00    188.66.231.191  ip-172-31-44-39.eu-west-1.compu GET /server-status HTTP/1.1
>
> 15-0   -   0/0/2   .   0.51    2225    19473   0.0 0.00    0.00    IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1 dev.mydomain.com    GET /courses/amazoncron HTTP/1.1

ubuntu@IP:etc/apache2/sites-available$ cat dev.mydomain.com

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain/public_html/dev
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName dev.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain/public_html/dev
    SSLENGINE on
    SSLCertificatekeyFile /etc/apache2/keys/mydomainRapidSSLCSRprivatekey.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/SSLCertificate-Key-File-mydomain-RapidSSL.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/certs/RapidSSL-Bundled-Intermediate-CA-mydomain.crt
    </VirtualHost>
```

I also can't figure out whether or not it's a process causing all of this ruckus:

```
    USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
    root         1  0.0  0.0  24300  1700 ?        Ss   Mar10  29:01 /sbin/init
    root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 [kthreadd]
    root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   4:38 [ksoftirqd/0]
    root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
    root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 [kworker/u:0]
    root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10 130:32 [migration/0]
    root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10  46:44 [watchdog/0]
    root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10 131:42 [migration/1]
    root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 [kworker/1:0]
    root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   5:32 [ksoftirqd/1]
    root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10  53:29 [watchdog/1]
    root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar10   0:00 [cpuset]
    root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar10   0:00 [khelper]
    root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
    root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar10   0:00 [netns]
    root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 [kworker/u:1]
    root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 [xenwatch]
    root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 [xenbus]
    root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10  11:08 [sync_supers]
    root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:16 [bdi-default]
    root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar10   0:00 [kintegrityd]
    root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar10   0:00 [kblockd]
    root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar10   0:00 [ata_sff]
    root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 [khubd]
    root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar10   0:00 [md]
    root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10 202:49 [kworker/0:1]
    root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:41 [khungtaskd]
    root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:53 [kswapd0]
    root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Mar10   0:00 [ksmd]
    root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
    root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
    root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar10   0:00 [crypto]
    root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar10   0:00 [kthrotld]
    root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 [khvcd]
    root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10 204:44 [kworker/1:1]
    root        62  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar10   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
    root       168  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10  54:19 [jbd2/xvda1-8]
    root       169  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar10   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
    root       281  0.0  0.0  17236   596 ?        S    Mar10   3:02 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
    root       283  0.0  0.0  21520   744 ?        Ss   Mar10   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
    root       336  0.0  0.0  21468   636 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
    root       337  0.0  0.0  21468   560 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
    root       431  0.0  0.0  15192   472 ?        S    Mar10   1:27 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
    root       476  0.0  0.0   4404   644 ?        S    Apr23   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
    root       478  0.0  0.0   7268  1020 ?        Ss   Mar10   0:22 dhclient3 -e IF_METRIC=100 -pf /var/run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases -1 eth0
    root       672  0.0  0.0  50036   860 ?        Ss   Mar10   0:01 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
    syslog     691  0.0  0.0 254492  5268 ?        Sl   Mar10  49:50 rsyslogd -c5
    102        698  0.0  0.0  23952  1140 ?        Ss   Mar10   1:03 dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart
    root       705  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar10   0:00 [kjournald]
    root       761  0.0  0.0  12936   168 tty4     Ss+  Mar10   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
    root       768  0.0  0.0  12936   164 tty5     Ss+  Mar10   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
    root       778  0.0  0.0  12936   160 tty2     Ss+  Mar10   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
    root       780  0.0  0.0  12936   164 tty3     Ss+  Mar10   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
    root       785  0.0  0.0  12936   168 tty6     Ss+  Mar10   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
    root       790  0.0  0.0   4332   148 ?        Ss   Mar10   0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
    root       792  0.0  0.0  19116   636 ?        Ss   Mar10   2:42 cron
    daemon     793  0.0  0.0  16912   160 ?        Ss   Mar10   0:01 atd
    root       824  0.0  0.0  12936   172 tty1     Ss+  Mar10   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
    whoopsie   837  0.0  0.0 187676  1476 ?        Ssl  Mar10   0:01 whoopsie
    mysql      857 35.5  3.3 1343920 253032 ?      Sl   Apr23 67594:24 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables --log-error=/va
    root      3432  0.0  0.0  73440  3580 ?        Ss   07:33   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv] 
    ubuntu    3572  0.1  0.0  74036  2200 ?        S    07:33   0:17 sshd: ubuntu@pts/2  
    ubuntu    3573  0.0  0.1  26764  9280 pts/2    Ss+  07:33   0:08 -bash
    root     10028  0.0  0.0  73440  3580 ?        Ss   08:39   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv] 
    ubuntu   10166  0.0  0.0  75348  3384 ?        S    08:39   0:06 sshd: ubuntu@pts/3  
    ubuntu   10167  0.0  0.1  26764  9228 pts/3    Ss+  08:39   0:03 -bash
    root     13876  0.6  0.1 373784 14560 ?        Ss   09:15   1:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data 13881  0.0  0.3 389276 26496 ?        S    09:15   0:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data 13885  0.0  0.3 389276 26856 ?        S    09:15   0:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data 19351  0.0  0.3 389308 26528 ?        S    10:14   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data 19851  0.0  0.3 388564 25984 ?        S    10:20   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data 19859  0.0  0.3 389564 27128 ?        S    10:20   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data 21562  0.0  0.4 396204 33428 ?        S    10:38   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data 21563  0.0  0.3 389276 26464 ?        S    10:38   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data 21596  0.0  0.3 391352 28492 ?        S    10:39   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data 21597  0.0  0.3 388508 25712 ?        S    10:39   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data 21598  0.0  0.3 390828 28000 ?        S    10:39   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    postfix  22581  0.0  0.0  27176  1604 ?        S    10:50   0:00 pickup -l -t fifo -u -c
    root     22894  0.0  0.0  73440  3580 ?        Ss   10:53   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv] 
    ubuntu   23045  0.1  0.0  75380  3648 ?        R    10:53   0:05 sshd: ubuntu@pts/1  
    ubuntu   23048  0.1  0.1  26732  9240 pts/1    Ss   10:53   0:04 -bash
    root     24910  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar19  19:07 [flush-202:1]
    root     26776  0.0  0.0  25112   512 ?        Ss   Mar20   6:21 /usr/lib/postfix/master
    postfix  26780  0.0  0.0  27340   920 ?        S    Mar20   2:32 qmgr -l -t fifo -u
    root     28284  0.0  0.0  17896   932 ?        S    11:47   0:00 /bin/bash /etc/mysql/debian-start
    root     28311  0.0  0.0   4596   592 ?        S    11:47   0:00 xargs -i /usr/bin/mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --skip-column-names --silent --batch --force -e {}
    mysql    28413  0.8  0.4 380644 33200 ?        Ssl  11:49   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
    root     28429  0.0  0.0  17896   928 ?        S    11:49   0:00 /bin/bash /etc/mysql/debian-start
    root     28458  0.0  0.0   4596   584 ?        R    11:49   0:00 xargs -i /usr/bin/mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --skip-column-names --silent --batch --force -e {}
    root     28475  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    11:49   0:00 [mysql] <defunct>
    postfix  28501  0.0  0.0  27280  1764 ?        S    11:50   0:00 cleanup -z -t unix -u -c
    postfix  28502  0.1  0.0  27188  1540 ?        S    11:50   0:00 trivial-rewrite -n rewrite -t unix -u -c
    postfix  28503  0.1  0.0  27420  2300 ?        S    11:50   0:00 local -t unix
    root     28535  5.0  0.0  99664  2016 ?        S    11:50   0:00 /usr/bin/mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --skip-column-names --silent --batch --force -e select count(*) into @discard from `mysql
```

ubuntu@IP:var/log/apache2$ cat error.log (partial dump of what I could fit in from the end)

```
    [Tue Sep 02 08:30:02 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 08:40:02 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 08:50:02 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 09:00:01 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 09:10:03 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 09:13:44 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:39 2014] [error] Init: Pass phrase incorrect
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:39 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:39 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218640442 error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:39 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:39 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:39 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 67710980 error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:39 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:39 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:57 2014] [error] Init: Pass phrase incorrect
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:57 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:57 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218640442 error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:57 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:57 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:57 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 67710980 error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:57 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
    [Tue Sep 02 09:14:57 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
    [Tue Sep 02 09:15:26 2014] [error] Init: Pass phrase incorrect
    [Tue Sep 02 09:15:26 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
    [Tue Sep 02 09:15:26 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218640442 error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
    [Tue Sep 02 09:15:26 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
    [Tue Sep 02 09:15:26 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
    [Tue Sep 02 09:15:26 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 67710980 error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
    [Tue Sep 02 09:15:26 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
    [Tue Sep 02 09:15:26 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
    [Tue Sep 02 09:15:37 2014] [warn] RSA server certificate wildcard CommonName (CN) `*.mydomain.com' does NOT match server name!?
    [Tue Sep 02 09:15:37 2014] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
    PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini on line 385 in Unknown on line 0
    [Tue Sep 02 09:15:37 2014] [warn] RSA server certificate wildcard CommonName (CN) `*.mydomain.com' does NOT match server name!?
    [Tue Sep 02 09:15:37 2014] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
    [Tue Sep 02 09:15:37 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Sep 02 09:19:41 2014] [error] [client IP2.IP2.IP2.IP2] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
    [Tue Sep 02 09:20:02 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 09:30:02 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 09:40:01 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 09:47:06 2014] [error] [client IP2.IP2.IP2.IP2] File does not exist: /var/www/server-info
    [Tue Sep 02 09:47:17 2014] [error] [client IP2.IP2.IP2.IP2] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/
    [Tue Sep 02 09:47:22 2014] [error] [client IP2.IP2.IP2.IP2] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/
    [Tue Sep 02 09:47:29 2014] [error] [client IP2.IP2.IP2.IP2] File does not exist: /var/www/dev
    [Tue Sep 02 09:47:37 2014] [error] [client IP2.IP2.IP2.IP2] File does not exist: /var/www/master
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 09:50:01 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 10:00:01 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 10:10:03 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 10:20:01 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 10:30:02 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 10:40:01 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 10:50:02 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 11:00:03 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 11:10:02 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 11:20:01 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 11:30:02 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 11:40:02 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 11:50:01 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    [Tue Sep 02 12:00:03 2014] [error] [client IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1] File does not exist: /var/www/courses
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
    chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mydomain/public_html/master/mydomain.com/app/webroot/custom/': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: I would start with getting your error.log cleaned up.
Fix the permission errors and figure out what that SSL error is about. Especialy "[Tue Sep 02 09:15:37 2014] [warn] RSA server certificate wildcard CommonName (CN) `*.mydomain.com' does NOT match server name!?" looks serious...

Comment: If I recall correctly, you need to bind your SSL certificate to one IP address, you can't use *:443, you need to pick one of your IPs and use it there, and update your domain accordingly. What is trying to change permissions?

Comment: Thing is SSL still isn't finalized, I could do as suggested but for the time being we have it added without dedicated IP. But that doesn't solve the problem.